CSP script-src settings reject inline-scripts in wordpress
Presently i have:
function add_csp_header() {
    $csp = "script-src 'nonce-".custom_nonce_value()."'"; //and some more
    header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
    header("Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
    header("Content-Security-Policy: $csp");
    }
add_action('send_headers', 'add_csp_header');

In the console i get several error messages saying:
Content-Security-Policy: the settings of the page have blocked loading a ressource on inline ("script-src").

The inline scripts are enqueued with wp_localize_script() like this:
wp_register_script( 'dibujos', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/dibujos.js',   array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true);
wp_localize_script( 'dibujos', 'archVar', array( 'url' => get_bloginfo('url') )    );
wp_enqueue_script('dibujos');

To add nonces to inline-scripts i tried the following approaches:
function toa_inline_script_nonce( array $attr ): array {
    if ( empty( $attr['id'] ) ) {
        return $attr;
    }
    if ( 'dibujos' === $attr['id'] ) {
        $attr['nonce']   = custom_nonce_value();
    }
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_script_attributes', 'toa_inline_script_nonce', 10, 1 );

does nothing, or...
//nonce for specific scripts
function toa_script_tag_nonce( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'jquery' OR $handle === 'admin-bar' OR $handle === 'dibujos' ) {
         $nonce = custom_nonce_value();
         $tag = str_replace( '<script ', '<script nonce="'.$nonce.'"', $tag );
    }
    return $tag;
    }
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'toa_script_tag_nonce', 10, 2 );

This adds nonces for the $handle 'jquery' and 'admin-bar', but ignores 'dibujos'.
and lastly...
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script_tag', 10, 3 );

function add_nonce_to_script_tag( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

  // Check the $handle and respond accordingly
  if ( $handle === 'dibujos' ) {
    $nonce_value = custom_nonce_value();
    $replace = sprintf("javascript' nonce='%s'>", $nonce_value );
    $tag = str_replace( "javascript'>", $replace, $tag);
  }

  return $tag;
}

// Then... $data is the inline JS from wherever
wp_add_inline_script('dibujos', $data, 'before');

This throws errors: $data is undefined and wp_add_inline_script() shouldn’t be called prior to wp_enqueue_scripts().
Conclusion: All my attempts to catch the script tag and add a nonce attribute failed. Somehow it appears that inline scripts are out of reach...(at least with these approaches)
In this post someone says:

Since these are echoed and  is hard
coded you cannot add an attribute to the HTML script elements of
wp_localize_script().

According to this statement inline-scripts are a dead-end for a save script-src CSP in wordpress. Despite of this saying, i wonder if this is really the case and if not, how can i add nonces to all inline scripts?

there is a filter wp_inline_script_attributes which can customise attributes for inline scripts :
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.6/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2919
then your plugin can look like this
add_filter("MY_PLUGIN/nonce_script", function ($_) {
    
    // put the data in cache to be sure to return the same value on all calls
    if (!isset($GLOBALS["MY_PLUGIN"]["nonce_script"])) {
        $GLOBALS["MY_PLUGIN"]["nonce_script"] = md5("塩" . microtime());
    }
    
    
    return $GLOBALS["MY_PLUGIN"]["nonce_script"];
    
});


add_action("send_headers", function ($wp) {
    
    $nonce_script = apply_filters("MY_PLUGIN/nonce_script", NULL);
    
    header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
    header("Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
    header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-$nonce_script'");
    
}, 10, 1);


add_filter("wp_script_attributes", function ($attributes) {
    
    $attributes["nonce"] = apply_filters("MY_PLUGIN/nonce_script", NULL);
    
    return $attributes;
    
}, 10, 1);


add_filter("wp_inline_script_attributes", function ($attributes, $data) {
    
    $attributes["nonce"] = apply_filters("MY_PLUGIN/nonce_script", NULL);
    
    return $attributes;
    
}, 10, 2);


thanks, look already much better, when inspecting the DOM. The nonces are present. However the variable $nonce-script in script-src 'nonce-$nonce_script' is undefined. Hence, the inline scripts are rejected. Any idea to make this work?

I changed your script a bit to make the variable work. Great answer. Thanks a lot.
